# My tkinter GUI freezes when the progress bar value is increased using a multi threaded functions

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, ttk

I have simple code using which I am trying to execute multiple threads where some heavy calculations are done in each thread and appropriately, the progress bar has to be updated. Sadly, when I click the START button, the Tkinter GUI freezes and never recovers. My code is as follows.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from threading import Thread

#########################################################################
def run():
    for i in range(1, 5001):
        P1['value'] = (i/5001)*100
        P1.update_idletasks()

#########################################################################

def thread():
    T1 = Thread(target=run)
    T1.start()
    T1.join()

#########################################################################

root = Tk()

B1 = Button(root, text='START', command=thread)
B1.grid(row=0, column=0)
P1 = Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=450, mode='determinate')
P1.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.geometry('500x35')
root.mainloop()

#########################################################################
```

Comment: Calling `T1.join()` will wait for the completion of the thread which will block the main thread.

Comment: Wow, I commented T1.join() out and it works like a charm